# Make Rails App Template CD to root and run bundle commands?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thor

I'm sure you can appreciate this attempt at laziness: I would like to improve my app template script in Rails 3.2.

I do something like
    `rails new APPNAME -m path/to/template.rb`

I would like to update the script to allow me to `cd` into the new application so I can run `bundle exec COMMAND`?

For example,

```
if compass = yes?("Would you like to install Compass and Susy?")
gem_group :assets do
 gem 'compass-rails'
 gem 'compass-susy-plugin'
end

     if compass == true
      run "bundle install"
      inside "#{Rails.application.class.parent_name}" do
        run "bundle exec compass install susy"
       end
 end
end
```

When I run the above code I get an error like -

```
unexpected keyword_do_block (SyntaxError)
  /home/rhodee/GitRepos/dotfiles/workflow.rb:103: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end,   expecting $end
```

Thank you for enabling my lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to remove the "inside" and simply execute

```
run "bundle exec compass install susy"
```

To actually move inside a directory and do something, you could:

```
run "cd #{Rails.application.class.parent_name}/public; rm index.html"
```

(Of course you could have run the above as run "rm public/index.html" but that's not the point.)

Comment: I'm going to upvote this because the script seems to a susy | compass installation issue. Thanks